# why is Poisson 's ratio for constant volume 0.5?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Is this ratio of longitudinal strain to lateral strain the same in all cases? And should we find relation between radius and length of the substance to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

Supposed you are pulling something uniaxially along the *x*-axis. Half the volume increase along the pulling direction comes from the the *y*-axis and half from the *z*-axis.

$$\Delta V_x +\Delta V_y + \Delta V_z = \Delta V_x -\frac{1}{2} \Delta V_x - \frac{1}{2} \Delta V_x = 0 $$

What is the change in volume along the *x*-axis? $\Delta V_x = (\ell_y \ell_z) \Delta \ell_x = (\ell_y \ell_z) (\ell_x \epsilon_x) = \epsilon_x V$

So the above relationship becomes

$$ \epsilon_y =- \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_x \\\epsilon_z =- \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_x $$